# Remove Last end node from Linked List in C++

Tags: c++

I want to remove the last end node from Linked List in C++.

My program has an exception. it is in a while loop.

How can I solve it? When the linked list has 1 node, program throw exception. the program works when we have more than 1 Node in the linked list.

> Exception thrown: read access violation. Start->**Next** was nullptr.
>   occurred

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int Data;
    Node* Next;
};

class LinkedList {

private:
    Node* Head = NULL;
    Node* Tail = NULL;
    Node* temp = NULL;

public:

    void Setup(int Data)
    {
        temp = new Node;
        temp->Data = Data;
        temp->Next = NULL;
        if (Head == NULL)
        {
            Head = temp;
            Tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Tail->Next = temp;
            Tail = Tail->Next;
        }
        cout << "Insert : " << Data << endl;
        //temp = NULL;
    }

    void Delete()
    {
        if (Head != NULL)
        {
            temp = Head;
            Head = Head->Next;
            cout << " Deleted Item is: " << temp->Data << endl;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " List is Empty \n";
        }
    }


    void DeleteFromEND()
    {
        Node* Start = Head;
        if (Start == NULL)
        {
            cout << " There is no item to delete!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (Start->Next != NULL)
        {
            while ((Start->Next)->Next != NULL)
            {
                Start = Start->Next;
            }
            temp = Start->Next;
            Start->Next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = Start;
        }
        cout << " Deleted Item From END: " << temp->Data << endl;
        delete temp;

    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList ls;
    ls.Setup(15);
    ls.Setup(1);
    ls.Setup(5);
    ls.Setup(9);
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND(); ls.DeleteFromEND(); ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.Setup(4);
    ls.Setup(545);
    //ls.Delete();
    ls.Setup(0);
    ls.Setup(-19);
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();
    ls.DeleteFromEND();

}
```

Comment: You can solve it by using a debugger.

Comment: What happens when you only have one or zero nodes in the list, where `Head->Next` or `Head` are null pointers?

Comment: I knew the problem. when we have two, one or zero nodes in the list, the pointer should point to the node that doesn't exist. but I don't know how can I fix it.

Comment: To begin with, `if (Start != nulltr)` (or possibly `if (Start == nullptr)` depending on what you want to do in this case).

Comment: Um... `temp = new Node;` then later, `Delete` does `free(temp)`, while `DeleteFromEND` does `delete temp`. The `free` invoke is wrong. `delete` what you `new`

Comment: I tried to see if the list is empty. but when a list is empty this code doesn't work.   if (Start == NULL) return;

Comment: This type of lists (single linked list with head and tail pointer) often use a _dummy node_. On list construction you create this valueless node, and the empty condition becomes `Head == Tail`, where `Head` and `Tail` are warranted to never be `NULL`. Then, when the list is destructed, you need to make sure that you delete all the nodes until the list is _empty_, and then delete the dummy node, which is basically doing either `delete Head` or `delete Tail` (but not both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a debugger like [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) to detect the part of code causing the exception. Also you can read more about your exception here: [Access violation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-can-i-debug-an-access-violation-q?view=vs-2019)

With that being said, your exception is happening because of this line: `while ((Start->Next)->Next != NULL)`. If you have only one item in your list, `Start->Next` would be **NULL** though you will get an exception when trying to access `(Start->Next)->Next`. To solve it just check if list has more than one item then start the while loop.

```
void DeleteFromEND()
{
    if(Head == NULL)
    {
        cout << " There is no item to delete!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node* Start = Head;
    if(Start->Next != NULL)
    {
        while ((Start->Next)->Next != NULL)
        {
            Start = Start->Next;
        }
        temp = Start->Next;
        Start->Next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = Start;
        Head = NULL;
    }
    cout << " Deleted Item From END: " << temp->Data << endl;
    delete temp;

}
```

Comment: And if the list has *no* nodes ? What then ?

Comment: It doesn't work. when list is empty we have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you, but we have the same problem.

Comment: @Hadi can you describe the problem? I have tested your code with changing this function now and it works fine.

Comment: when a list is empty this code doesn't work. because this condition doesn't true. if (Head == NULL) return;

Comment: @Hadi When the list is empty this function should not do anything. I don't understand the problem. Please give a sample code in which case you are facing the issue.

Comment: @ImanKianrostami Can I send a photo or more sample code here? I don't see this ability.

Comment: @ImanKianrostami See, when the list is empty Head is 0x00b4e710 {Data=-572662307 Next=0xdddddddd {Data=??? Next=??? } } and doesn't equal to NULL then condition isn't true so inside the condition doesn't work.

Comment: @Hadi have you tested the code? I tried calling `ls.DeleteFromEND();` immediately after  `LinkedList ls;` and it worked just fine. I cannot help if I can't reproduce your problem that's why I asked you to edit the question

Comment: @Hadi Ok now it makes sense ;) You should set `Head` variable to NULL when the list is empty. See updated code.

Answer (score 1):

In your function **DeleteFromEND()**, you just need to check if this is the last node.

```
if(start->next == NULL){
   // write code to delete single node
}
else{
  // your remaining code
}
```

This way your code will work for last node deletion.

Comment: This will generate an exception if the list is empty and `start` is NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use debugger to check which part is causing issue to the code. Btw This is how last node is deleted.

```
struct node* delete_last(struct node* head)
 {  int i;  
 if(head == NULL){ // if list is empty.
  return head;
}
if(haed->next->next == NULL){ // if list has only 1 element.
  free(head); 
  return head;
}
 struct node* temp1 = head; 
while(temp1->next->next!=NULL)  
 {  temp1 = temp1->next;    }   
 struct node* temp2 = temp1->next; 
temp1->next=temp2->next;    
 free(temp2);   
 return head;
  }
```